# OmniDazzle alternative for modern Macs?

Tags: screen-capture, utilities, video-capture

Is there any tool that runs on current Macs providing a flashlight effect to highlight a portion on the screen?

In the past I've used OmniDazzle to create screen casts using this effect.
On recent OS X versions it doesn't work any more, though..

Any hint appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'd recommend [Mouseposé](http://boinx.com/mousepose/overview/). It's very similar in spirit to OmniDazzle but works with recent versions of Mac OS X.

One nice feature is that if you pause for a little bit, Mouseposé will expand the highlight from the pointer to the whole window.

Comment: Looks great, cheers! Though horribly expensive for a util that does pretty much one thing only ;-)

Comment: Sometimes you can get it in a "big bundle," which is how I have my copy. :-)

Comment: Even worse, since it’s a subscription price.

Comment: @Manngo - that’s new and an unfortunate development.